# When did “reinvent myself” come into use? Was there a belief a person could do that for many decades? It seems a new bilief to me

Tags: idiomatic-language

When did “reinvent myself” come into use?
Was there a belief a person could do that for many decades?  It seems a new bilief to me
I think it is a falsehood
Is there debate?
Thanks!
Elizabeth

Comment: Welcome to ELL, but questions like this are better suited to English Language and Usage, since they're not about learning English but about ideas. https://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It is an idiomatic   expression probably from psicological  studies. Its early usages available on [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reinvent%20oneself%2Creinvent%20yourself&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creinvent%20oneself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creinvent%20yourself%3B%2Cc0) date back to late ‘70s/early‘80s

[Reinvent oneself:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reinvent%20oneself)

> : to become a different kind of person, performer, etc. *She's a classical singer who's trying to reinvent herself as a pop artist*.

From [Prophecies & Transformations:](https://books.google.it/books?id=-j6wAAAAIAAJ&q=%22reinvent%20yourself%22&dq=%22reinvent%20yourself%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib3Jyh1dfcAhWK66QKHUCYA94Q6AEILjAC)  1978

> ... reinvent your body discover your mind you will do this now America drink the Poet's milk of vision disrobe touch yourself dismantle the tar discover your mind reinvent yourself now